# Some of the views in my fragment have a constant functionality, how can I code that functionality such that it is run only once?

Tags: android, fragment

**For example**: I have a button in my fragment and clicking that button will display a toast message which is same every time. Since the view will be inflated only after onCreateView() method is run, is there a way where I the onClickListener() of the button is initialized only once.

Comment: could you post code for understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend use DataBinding library to implement onClick statically.

Only pass application context to prevent memory leak!
Even better if you make the Toaster class non-static and pass it as a parameter to layout using "variable" tag in "data".

DataBinding integration guide:
[Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="path.to.Toaster"/>
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> Toaster.makeToast()}"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Toaster.class:

```
package path.to;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Toaster {

    public static Context context;

    public static void makeToast() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Just a toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try that

Comment: You welcome :)
There is a lot more to discover in that library.
You can apply a lot of logic directly in the layout.

Comment: You’re welcome to mark my answer as an accepted answer. Of course only if it indeed answers your question :)